# Android (Kotlin): Change Background of an ImageButton in a function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-drawable, imagebutton

Question: How can I declare the ImageButton public, like in Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton b1;
```

Problem:
This code works as expected:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
   val b1 = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btn_switch) as ImageButton
   b1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.switch_gray)`
```

Within a public fun outside onCreate{} the same code crashes my app:

```
private fun myfunction(it: String?) {
        if (output == "false") { findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btn_switch).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.switch_red)  }
```

Comment: "the same code crashes my app". Look at the stacktrace, it should tell you why. Also is `output` not supposed to be `it` in your function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create variable for ImageButton about the onCreate() method, within the class

```
private lateinit var b1: ImageButton
```

This code was equivalent to `ImageButton b1;` this Java code.

later on you can initialize that ImageButton in onCreate and use it anywhere within the class.

Comment: And also could you share the stacktrace, So we can know the exact reason for the crash.

Comment: that's what I was looking for